# Debian Jessie (Raspberry Pi) Install Postgres 9.6

Tags: linux, debian

I'm having difficulty installing Postgres 9.6 on my Raspberry Pi running Debian 8 (Jessie). I've tried two paths:

1. According to [these instructions](https://tecadmin.net/install-postgresql-on-debian/):

   - Add a `pgdg.list` file to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` containing `deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ jessie-pgdg main`
   - `wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -`
   - `sudo apt-get update`, here I get an error:

     W: Failed to fetch
     http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/jessie-pgdg/InRelease
     Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' in 
     Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

     E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or 
     old ones used instead.
   - The error makes sense because there are no armhf packages in `http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/jessie-pgdg/InRelease`
   - So running `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6` results in a package not found error.
2. This [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43751899/not-able-to-download-postgresql-9-6-1-version-on-raspberry-pi-3-os-debian-jes):

   - Start by removing the `pgdg.list` from the previous example.
   - Create a `backports.list` file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` containing `deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main`
   - `sudo apt-get update` & `sudo apt-get upgrade` - both succeed w/o errors.
   - `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6` which gives me this error:

     `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     postgresql-9.6 : Depends: postgresql-common (>= 171~) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: ssl-cert but it is not installable
     Recommends: postgresql-contrib-9.6 but it is not going to be installed
     Recommends: sysstat but it is not installable
     E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

It looks like the backports repository is the better one to use, but should I have to manually install Postgres's package deps (postgresql-common,postgresql-contrib-9.6 etc)? Why does the recommended way with the offical PGDG repository tell me it's missing binary-armhf packages? What is the proper repo and method of install for this? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. But I resolved it using:

```
http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
```

Then I ran:

```
sudo apt install postgresql-common/jessie-backports
sudo apt install postgresql-client-9.6/jessie-backports
sudo apt install postgresql-9.6/jessie-backports
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no postgresql-9.6 for jessie in armhf backport installation is suggested:
This one solved for me:

1. Run`sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list`, then add

   ```
    deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
   ```
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get -t jessie-backports install postgresql-9.6`

Comment: You appear to have two accounts, would you like to have them merged? https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/91034/hithesh-karanth and https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/91033/hithesh-karanth